In FlashList of shopify,setting the height to 500px doesn't shrink the list if the content is smaller, unlike in React Native's FlatList
I used a flatlist in React Native before. When I set the list height to 500px, the flatlist would automatically shrink to the content size if the content was smaller, but it would take a maximum of 500px if the content was larger. However, in the flashlist of Shopify, when I set the height to 500px, it would not shrink like the flatlist does when the content is smaller. This caused the UI to look weird.
 <View style={{ flex: !height && 1 }}>
      <SearchFilterComponent
        columns={columns}
        initialValues={{ filters: tableFilters?.filters }}
        onSubmitFilters={onSubmitFilters}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          height: height || Dimensions.get("screen").height - 210,
        }}
      >
        <FlashList
          data={tableData.data}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={tableData?.pageable && handleRefresh}
          onEndReachedThreshold={1}
          onEndReached={() => {
            tableData?.pageable && fetchNextPage();
          }}
          ListEmptyComponent={!(isLoading || refreshing || tableData?.data?.length) && <Empty />}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => <RenderMemoItem item={item} index={index} />}
          estimatedItemSize={400}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(item?.id || index)}
          ListFooterComponent={
            <>
              {!isLoading && footer && <>{footer}</>}
              {isLoading && <Loader count={10} />}
            </>
          }
        />
      </View>
      {onCreateAction || actions?.length ? (
        <FloatingAction
          showBackground={false}
          actionsPaddingTopBottom={0}
          actions={actions}
          color="#1F62FF"
          iconHeight={28}
          iconWidth={28}
          buttonSize={51}
          floatingIcon={<Octicons name="plus" size={32} color="white" />}
          onPressBackdrop={() => null}
          onPressMain={() => {
            onCreateAction && onCreateAction();
          }}
          onPressItem={(name) => {}}
        />
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </View>

i have tried with minimum height, but it is still not working. When there is only one item on the list, it takes up the entire 500px.
